# How to look for a string inside an array of objects(structure)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here is a small example:

```
var distinctValues = [];
distinctValues.push("Value1");
distinctValues.push("Value2");

var firstValue = distinctValues[0];

var searchResults = [];

var data = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
data.forEach(function (row) {

  searchResults[searchResults.length] =
  {
    "ID"       : row.ID,
    "CreatedBy": row.CreatedBy,
    "UpdatedBy": row.UpdatedBy
  }
}
```

How do I look firstValue("Value1") inside searchResults array and retrieve the CreatedBy information?

```
//something like this - this is wrong syntax by the way
if ($.inArray(firstValue, searchResults) != -1) {
      alert(searchResults["CreatedBy"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may want to do this:

```
var searchResults = [];
data.forEach(function (row) {

  searchResults.push({ //Push to push the record to the array
    "ID"       : row.ID,
    "CreatedBy": row.CreatedBy,
    "UpdatedBy": row.UpdatedBy
  });
}
```

You can use jquery $.inArray or [Array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

searchResults is an array of objects so use indexer i.e `searchResults[index]["CreatedBy"]` instead of  `searchResults["CreatedBy"]`:

```
var idx = searchResults.indexOf(firstValue); //or var idx = $.inArray(firstValue, searchResults)
if (idx  > -1) {
      alert(searchResults[idx]["CreatedBy"]);  //item Found
}
```

Nothing wrong with your syntax for [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/),  Provided you have jquery included in your code.

Since your match is against an object property you can try this:

```
   var result = $.grep(searchResults, function(value)
   {
       return value.ID === firstValue;
   });

  console.log(result[0].CreatedBy); //result will be an array of matches.
```

Comment: we can use `arr[arr.length]` for adding elements .. but `arr.push` is more fastest

Comment: Unfortunately that always returns -1. I debugged it and can see that the value exists in the array :-(

Comment: @Max How does your array look and value? Definitely has to be some issue with the data only... can you a console.log of your array and the data you are trying to compare. We will try it in a fiddle.

Comment: I also tried:             var arr = $.grep(searchJobInfoResults, function (n, i) {
                return (n == value);
            });

Comment: Here is it:
TraceInfo("Value: " + value);
TraceInfo("1st element: " + searchJobInfoResults[0]["GroupInstanceID"]);
TraceInfo("1st element: " + searchJobInfoResults[0]["CreatedBy"]);

Value: e6cc8074-d51f-4038-bc97-a3bd22e53bc7 
1st element: e6cc8074-d51f-4038-bc97-a3bd22e53bc7 
1st element: DOMAIN01\JOHNB

Comment: @Max i cant make out anythingfrom this. Just do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(searchResults))` and `firstValue` in chrome console and put it in a fiddle. Also what is `firstValue` in your case  is it an object or a property value?

Comment: sorry I never used fiddle, only Fiddler. Here is the output:

console.log(value);
console.log(JSON.stringify(searchJobInfoResults));

LOG: cfe17945-6892-4990-a103-d308db160997 
LOG: 
[{"GroupInstanceID":"cfe17945-6892-4990-a103-d308db160997","CreatedBy":"DOMAIN01\\JOHN"},
{"GroupInstanceID":"bb130ad3-7c50-459e-b000-95017df398b2","CreatedBy":"DOMAIN01\\JOHN"}] 

firstValue is a string I suppose. This value comes from the value param below. I get each value from another array:
$.each(distinctGroupInstanceIDs, function (index, value)

not sure if this is what you wanted to see. -- thanks!

Comment: @Max Check this fiddle you need to do this way with grep http://jsfiddle.net/vhVjQ/. But again i am not sure if this is what you are looking for since not sure about the data.

Comment: oh crap, I was forgetting to include the ".GroupInstanceID" ! So instead of n == value, I needed n.GroupInstanceID == value :)
Also both "==" and "===" works, not sure what the difference is. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Max yup both works but only thing is that == just checks for the value but === checks for type and value match... After you gave the actual data and what you are trying to do, i got the solution.. :)